# Диалектное ли слово "посахарить"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, диалекты

Недавно употребил в речи слово "посахарить", что покоробило мою жену, которая утверждает, что это какое-то диалектное слово, которое никогда не употреблялось в её окружении. При этом слово находится в нескольких интернет-словарях, но без каких-либо комментариев или частот употребления. Итак, каков статус этого слова?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В словарях (Ожегов, Ушаков) это слово приводится без ограничительных пометок, указывается пара совершенного и несовершенного видов (посахарить/сахарить). Значение - "посыпать сахаром" или "добавить во что-то сахара".
У Даля упоминается пословица:

> Чужую беду, не посоля, уплету, а свою, и посахарив, не проглочу.

По-видимому, слово подзабыто, чаще одним словом говорят "подсластить".

Answer (score 1):

Диалектные слова — это слова, употребляемые только жителями той или иной местности. Слово *посахарить* встречается в различных словарях, но нигде не обозначено как диалектное.

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x) помечает его как разговорное.

В Нацкорпусе я нашел только одно вхождение "посахари" и два — "посахаренные".

Comment: Ну, в данном случае, я реально имел в виду "диалектное", потому что было утверждение, что это что-то "уральское".